# K-maps, do they completely simplify?

Tags: boolean-algebra, state-machines, karnaugh-map

I've been told that K-maps produce a completely simplified boolean equation, and they can't or shouldnt be simplified anymore after that. However, on allaboutcircuits.com they were able to simplify an equation more after the k-map. So what gives? Is this just an exception? Or is there something else I'm missing?

This is the k-map in question. 
[image: K-map D.a]
As you can see, D.a is simplified further after the k-map is done. It goes from A*I + B*I to (A+B)*I

For context, here's the full article. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-11/finite-state-machines/

Comment: Depends what is meant by "simplify". K-map is giving you the minimal SOP or POS. If you "circle" the zeros in it, you will have the other result (The minimal POS).

Comment: Ohh, I think I get it now. So k-map will produce the simplest SOP/POS. They can still be simplified further though, in this case so the circuit will have less gates. Thank you :)

Comment: The final result is actually a minimal POS.

Comment: Oh yes your right, I just solved the k-map for POS and it results in the final result they got. Thanks again!

Comment: I just added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The K-Map is producing either the minimal Sum Of Products (SOP), if "circling" the ones, or the minimal Product of Sums (POS), if circling the zeros. Let's do the latter (my grouping is using the red line):

[image]

Now, the group of 4 is giving us \$I\$ (as it is the only term which has the same value of \$0\$ in this group) and the group of two is giving us \$A+B\$. So the final result is \$I\cdot(A+B)\$.